# Emulator crashing when trying to run an application with multiple images

Tags: android

I get this error message when trying to run an application with large size image

> 04-07 08:32:01.837: E/dalvikvm-heap(647): 20736000-byte external
>   allocation too large for this process. 04-07 08:32:01.897:
>   E/GraphicsJNI(647): VM won't let us allocate 20736000 bytes

Any help?

Comment: try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8250704/1056359

Answer (score 0):

Try reading [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) and see if it works.

Comment: This depends on images urls which forces me to upload the pictures and forces the user to have an internet connection.